# Is 1password vulnerable to NSA spying?

Tags: nsa

In light of the recent heartbleed vulnerability, I'm thinking of switching to a service like 1Password.  However, I don't know how to evaluate the risk of NSA (or other government) spying.  So, two questions: how can I evaluate the risk of such spying, and is 1Password secure from it?

**EDIT:** I thought it went without saying, but I'm interested in answers that explain the rationale used.  I'm not interested in baseless opinion about 1Password (like "1Password sucks!"), but I am interested in impartial criticism, with an emphasis on how one can evaluate services like it with respect to this vulnerability.  Also, please back up any opinions with facts and references.

**EDIT 2:** I realize that asking for definitive proof of spying is unrealistic.  I'm asking for a way of evaluating the risks.  For example, if they claimed to be free of government spying, that would be useful information.  (They make no such claim, as far as I can tell.)  Or perhaps it is significant that they are a Canadian company.  I don't know, and I would appreciate help from you security experts.

Comment: I would like this question to be reopened.  The [Don't Ask](http://security.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) page details the sorts of subjective questions that don't belong on this site.  My question is not one of those.  On the same page, it lists criteria for *constructive* subjective questions that *do* belong on this site, and my question meets all of these criteria, especially after the edit.

Comment: I don't know 1password, but lastpass for instance never stores your passwords, and are always encrypted if stored locally, so I would ask how 1password stores passwords. at least if they don't store them it'd be impossible for the NSA/CIA to get them unless they do a MITM attack or put in a keylogger, which is much more difficult then giving 1password a subpoena

Comment: Personally, I don;t think this qualifies for reopening, as there is not going to be a valid answer, just opinions. Your second edit helps, but you will need to completely edit the question. I am guessing you want to ask "How can I evaluate the security of a piece of software?" - which may be answerable as long as you don't want an answer stating 'this is safe' or 'this is unsafe'

Comment: This could have been the basis for a good, objective, relevant answer: [Who Has Your Back? A Report from the Electronic Frontier Foundation](https://www.eff.org/who-has-your-back-government-data-requests-2014)

Answer (score 13):

If some three-letter agency is after you, personally, then you are doomed. They already put a microphone in your home, maybe even a video camera with a good view on your screen and keyboard.

If the same three-letter agency does its job properly (and you should hope for it, since it is paid with *your* tax money), then knowing whether they bribed any given online service cannot be answered: a positive answer, one way or the other, would be a proof of incompetence of the said agency.

In any case, what makes you believe that a random guy on the Internet like me would be trustworthy ? There is no way that your question may find here an answer that you can count upon. Be rational in your paranoia !

Comment: Maybe you are in fact not a black bear, but an NSA agent :O

Comment: Why can't he be both!? Mice study us while we think our scientists study them, bears have even bigger brains, think about it!

Comment: black bear? What is blackbear?

Answer (score 3):

By definition, if you could evaluate their spying, then it's not spying.

And, if you had the mean to actually find out whether they are spying on you, they you are *definitely* worth spying on - and there's your answer.

On the other hand, 1Password does you the same good than, say, installing a two-factor biometric keypad on your front door during a flood. If your password is "secure" but an attacker can read it directly from a server's memory you're barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: Good answer, but I thought it's "barking *up* the wrong tree" ;)